# How to run OpenOCD on CLion with custom openocd and gdb parameters?

Tags: debugging, clion, openocd, clion-plugins

How run debug session whith custom parametrs?
Exemple:

arm-none-eabi-gdb-py ex "target extended-remote |openocd -c 'gdb_port 3333; log_output ./debug/openocd.log' -f interface/stlink.cfg -c 'transport select hla_swd' -f ./debug/stm32wbx.cfg -c 'stm32wbx.cpu configure -rtos auto'" -ex "source ./debug/gdbinit" -ex "source ./debug/FreeRTOS/FreeRTOS.py" -ex "source ./debug/flipperapps.py" -ex "fap-set-debug-elf-root build/f7-firmware-D/.extapps" -ex "source ./debug/PyCortexMDebug/PyCortexMDebug.py" -ex "svd_load ./debug/STM32WB55_CM4.svd" -ex compare-sections build/latest/firmware.elf

I try add before launch script, but clion either hangs, or if you specify an exit from gdb in the script - clion runs its parameters over the script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything works through the option "embedded gdb server"
Example:

[image]